# How to use context.Forward with autofac

Tags: c#, autofac, botframework

I am trying to build a bot using Microsoft Bot Framework and Autofac.
I have a service which is shared between 2 **Dialogs** and the first **Dialog** instantiates the other based on a user response.
Inside my **Dialog** I invoke this line:

```
await context.Forward(new StepDialog(_productProvider, _groups, _products,  0), ResumeAfter, new Activity { Text = category }, CancellationToken.None);
```

But I don't think this is right. In my controller, I do this:

```
// Create our scope
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, model))
{

    // Create our conversation
    await Conversation.SendAsync(model, () => scope.Resolve<IDialog<object>>());
};
```

So I assume that I have to do something similar to get the instance of my **StepDialog** while maintaining the reference to the **ProductProvider** (which is my service).

I thought about passing the scope into the constructor of my initial **Dialog** but I have read that is a bad idea, so how can I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One idea that I have seen working pretty well is to use a Dialog Factory; so you inject that into your dialog and use it to resolve other dialogs.

In the [ContosoFlowers sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers) you will find a basic implementation of a Dialog Factory. Below some reference links:

- The base [DialogFactory](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers.BotAssets/Dialogs/DialogFactory.cs)
- The [ContosoFlowersDialogFactory](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/ContosoFlowersDialogFactory.cs) which is just inheriting from the base DialogFactory and adding a new method for a case not covered by the base factory.
- [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowersModule.cs#L18) is how the factory and dialogs are being registered in AutoFac
- [Here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/demo-ContosoFlowers/ContosoFlowers/Dialogs/RootDialog.cs#L80) is how the dialog factory is being used

Comment: This definitely answered my question, it isn't working perfectly, but it answers everything in the scope of this question :)